# Where can I find some publicly available dataset for retail store companies?

Tags: data-request, shopping

I am looking for some publicly available dataset for retail store companies which (preferably) includes data about there stores and operations. I tried to look around but couldn't find any dataset related to retail store companies. Does anyone know about such datasets that I can view and download(free or paid-any option)?

Comment: duplicate posted twice by the same user